# Can I compile a sketch for my attiny85 without an arduino board?

Tags: avr, nrf24l01+

I have a lot of Raspberry Pi's laying around, so I want to use those to program my attiny85 chips. The problem is that most of the code examples, libraries, and documentation out there assume you're using Arduino. Can I run Arduino commandline software on my Raspberry Pi, and use that to program the attiny85?

I'm trying to compile an RF24 program for the attiny using avr-g++, but I'm running into too many dependency errors, and I wonder if things will just be easier if I use Arduino software.`

Comment: I would suggest that things might be easier if you _don't_ use the Arduino software. The AVR toolchain should work well in just about any *nix environment, as well as the command line programming tools.

Comment: The answer is s simple and plain **yes**. I know this is not a very useful answer, but you did not provide enough details about your problem to enable people to write useful answers.

Comment: *Can I run Arduino commandline software on my Raspberry Pi?* - what command line software are you referring to? The Arduino IDE has a GUI interface.

Comment: By "program the attiny85", do you mean "upload an already build program to the attiny85" or do you mean "build an executable program for attiny85 from source code", or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't you be able to?

The compiler runs on the computer, not on the Arduino board. You don't need a board to be connected to compile either. If you enable verbose output during compile in the Arduino IDE settings it will tell you where it puts the resulting .hex file, after which you can use `avr-dude` to upload it to the target MCU.

If you want to use Arduino libraries you'll need to use an core for ATTiny devices (e.g. ATTinyCore). But either way you don't need an Arduino board to compile.

---

I'd also echo what @Marcus says, for the small devices you are better off completely ditching the Arduino stuff (it's such badly written, bloated, and inefficient), and simply starting with a nice clean C file.

There is nothing stopping you using the Arduino IDE or the `avr-libc` tools which it uses. If you add your own `main()` function in a C file and don't put anything in the `.ino` file you will be able to compile without any of the bloat.

Answer (score 0):

"Arduino" makes a statement on the mcu in use.

Technologically, it's extremely unlikely you could run most sketches on devices with less than 1kB of RAM (largest SRAM in Attiny85 is 512 B; most models are smaller).

So, no. The idea "microcontrollers are by now capable enough to run a C++ subset on them directly" behind arduino simply doesn't seem to apply to the Attiny85.

However, there's the "cuteduino", which actually should work with a small set of basic Arduino libraries. It's based on the Attiny85.

I'd argue that you simply *don't want to* use Arduino on Attinies; these devices are so resource-constrained, that you probably want to keep in control.

Now, the RF24 lib comes with non-arduino attiny85 support, so go for that? http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/ATTiny.html

Answer (score 0):

You can disregard the answers that say you can't compile for the ATtiny85 using the Arduino IDE. I have done so many times, for example my [torch locator](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12769) project which uses the ATtiny85 and the Arduino IDE to compile for it.

Here's my "board":

[image: Torch locator (1)]

View from other side:

[image: Torch locator (2)]

Code:

```c++
// ATtiny85 torch detector
// Author: Nick Gammon
// Date: 25 February 2015

// ATMEL ATTINY 25/45/85 / ARDUINO
// Pin 1 is /RESET
//
//                  +-\/-+
// Ain0 (D 5) PB5  1|    |8  Vcc
// Ain3 (D 3) PB3  2|    |7  PB2 (D 2) Ain1 
// Ain2 (D 4) PB4  3|    |6  PB1 (D 1) pwm1
//            GND  4|    |5  PB0 (D 0) pwm0
//                  +----+

/*

  Pin 2 (PB3) <-- LDR (GL5539) --> Pin 7 (PB2) <----> 56 k <----> Gnd

  Pin 5 (PB0) <---- LED ---> 100 R <-----> Gnd

*/


#include <avr/sleep.h>    // Sleep Modes
#include <avr/power.h>    // Power management
#include <avr/wdt.h>      // Watchdog timer

const byte LED = 0;          // pin 5 
const byte LDR_ENABLE = 3;   // pin 2
const byte LDR_READ = 1;     // Ain1 (PB2) pin 7
const int LIGHT_THRESHOLD = 200;  // Flash LED when darker than this

 // when ADC completed, take an interrupt 
EMPTY_INTERRUPT (ADC_vect);

// Take an ADC reading in sleep mode (ADC)
float getReading (byte port)
  {
  power_adc_enable() ;
  ADCSRA = bit (ADEN) | bit (ADIF);  // enable ADC, turn off any pending interrupt

  // set a2d prescale factor to 128
  // 8 MHz / 128 = 62.5 KHz, inside the desired 50-200 KHz range.

  ADCSRA |= bit (ADPS0) | bit (ADPS1) | bit (ADPS2); 

  if (port >= A0)
    port -= A0;

#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__)  
  ADMUX = (port & 0x07);  // AVcc   
#else   
  ADMUX = bit (REFS0) | (port & 0x07);  // AVcc   
#endif

  noInterrupts ();
  set_sleep_mode (SLEEP_MODE_ADC);    // sleep during sample
  sleep_enable();  

  // start the conversion
  ADCSRA |= bit (ADSC) | bit (ADIE);
  interrupts ();
  sleep_cpu ();     
  sleep_disable ();

  // reading should be done, but better make sure
  // maybe the timer interrupt fired 

  // ADSC is cleared when the conversion finishes
  while (bit_is_set (ADCSRA, ADSC))
    { }

  byte low  = ADCL;
  byte high = ADCH;

  ADCSRA = 0;  // disable ADC
  power_adc_disable();

  return (high << 8) | low;

  }  // end of getReading

// watchdog interrupt
ISR (WDT_vect) 
{
   wdt_disable();  // disable watchdog
}  // end of WDT_vect

#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__)  
  #define watchdogRegister WDTCR
#else
  #define watchdogRegister WDTCSR
#endif

void setup ()
  {
  wdt_reset();  
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LDR_ENABLE, OUTPUT);
  ADCSRA = 0;            // turn off ADC
  power_all_disable ();  // power off ADC, Timer 0 and 1, serial interface
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  // power up the LDR, take a reading
  digitalWrite (LDR_ENABLE, HIGH);
  int value = getReading (LDR_READ);
  // power off the LDR
  digitalWrite (LDR_ENABLE, LOW);

  // if it's dark, flash the LED for 2 mS
  if (value < LIGHT_THRESHOLD)
    {
    power_timer0_enable ();
    delay (1);  // let timer reach a known point
    digitalWrite (LED, HIGH);
    delay (2); 
    digitalWrite (LED, LOW);
    power_timer0_disable ();
    }

  goToSleep ();
  }  // end of loop

void goToSleep ()
  {
  set_sleep_mode (SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
  noInterrupts ();       // timed sequence coming up

  // pat the dog
  wdt_reset();  

  // clear various "reset" flags
  MCUSR = 0;     
  // allow changes, disable reset, clear existing interrupt
  watchdogRegister = bit (WDCE) | bit (WDE) | bit (WDIF);
  // set interrupt mode and an interval (WDE must be changed from 1 to 0 here)
  watchdogRegister = bit (WDIE) | bit (WDP2) | bit (WDP1) | bit (WDP0);    // set WDIE, and 2 seconds delay

  sleep_enable ();       // ready to sleep
  interrupts ();         // interrupts are required now
  sleep_cpu ();          // sleep                
  sleep_disable ();      // precaution
  }  // end of goToSleep
```

Compiled under the IDE it uses 16% of program memory:

```
Sketch uses 1,370 bytes (16%) of program storage space. Maximum is 8,192 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes of dynamic memory.
```

Claims that the Arduino IDE is badly written and inefficient are not generally true. To a certain extent the Arduino libraries favour ease-of-use over compactness, however you don't have to use them.

The IDE is just a front-end to the avr-g++ compiler. It is easy to use, and produces a .hex file which you can then upload to your chip using a suitable ICSP interface.

The avr-g++ compiler itself does aggressive code optimization. You won't get any advantage from ditching the IDE and using the avr-g++ compiler yourself - it's the same compiler. And if you think you can do better in assembler, good luck! The compiler-writers know all the tricks for storing variables in registers, and minimizing code in various ways. You will be hard pressed to write better code than the compiler generates anyway.

---

Claims that the IDE generates bloated code are Complete Nonsense. Take this sketch:

```c++
int main ()
  {
  DDRB = bit (2);  // pin 7 on chip

  while (true)
    {
    PINB = bit (2); // blink it
    }
  }
```

Compiled for the ATtiny85 under the IDE 1.6.9 I get this program memory usage:

```
Sketch uses 60 bytes (0%) of program storage space. Maximum is 8,192 bytes.
Global variables use 0 bytes of dynamic memory.
```

There are 15 interrupt vectors at the start of program memory, for which space has to be reserved. So 30 of those bytes are accounted for by that unavoidable overhead.

Here is the full disassembly of the above:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:   0e c0           rjmp    .+28        ; 0x1e <__ctors_end>
   2:   15 c0           rjmp    .+42        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
   4:   14 c0           rjmp    .+40        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
   6:   13 c0           rjmp    .+38        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
   8:   12 c0           rjmp    .+36        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
   a:   11 c0           rjmp    .+34        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
   c:   10 c0           rjmp    .+32        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
   e:   0f c0           rjmp    .+30        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
  10:   0e c0           rjmp    .+28        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
  12:   0d c0           rjmp    .+26        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
  14:   0c c0           rjmp    .+24        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
  16:   0b c0           rjmp    .+22        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
  18:   0a c0           rjmp    .+20        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
  1a:   09 c0           rjmp    .+18        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>
  1c:   08 c0           rjmp    .+16        ; 0x2e <__bad_interrupt>

0000001e <__ctors_end>:
  1e:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  20:   1f be           out 0x3f, r1    ; 63
  22:   cf e5           ldi r28, 0x5F   ; 95
  24:   d2 e0           ldi r29, 0x02   ; 2
  26:   de bf           out 0x3e, r29   ; 62
  28:   cd bf           out 0x3d, r28   ; 61
  2a:   02 d0           rcall   .+4         ; 0x30 <main>
  2c:   05 c0           rjmp    .+10        ; 0x38 <_exit>

0000002e <__bad_interrupt>:
  2e:   e8 cf           rjmp    .-48        ; 0x0 <__vectors>

00000030 <main>:
  30:   84 e0           ldi r24, 0x04   ; 4
  32:   87 bb           out 0x17, r24   ; 23
  34:   86 bb           out 0x16, r24   ; 22
  36:   fe cf           rjmp    .-4         ; 0x34 <main+0x4>

00000038 <_exit>:
  38:   f8 94           cli

0000003a <__stop_program>:
  3a:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0x3a <__stop_program>
```

I can't see much bloat there.

---

> I wonder if things will just be easier if I use Arduino software

Yes, much easier.

Comment: Although your answer is OK, I think it does not answer the main OP question: is it possible to program ATtiny85 chips on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Does the Pi not use Unix? The Arduino IDE runs under Unix. I run it myself under Ubuntu.

Comment: @jfpoilpret  The question was actually *Can I run Arduino commandline software on my Raspberry Pi?* - **what** Arduino commandline software?

Comment: Well I would say this one: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc

Comment: That's because you are bypassing all of the bloat by adding your own `main()` function. Try doing the same with `loop()` instead you'll end up with 326 bytes - that's a 400% overhead on top of the simple one. But also you are using direct port access rather than `digitalWrite()` which is again bypassing the bloat. Try doing `digitalWrite()` in `loop()` and you'll end up with 812 bytes - a 1200% overhead! Tell me, would you consider that bloat?

Comment: @TomCarpenter - as I said, functions like digitalWrite allow for a variable pin number to be passed, as opposed to a constant. For that to be looked up at runtime takes code. It is designed to be beginner-friendly. If you don't want to use those functions, then don't.

Comment: Unix can be different binary-wise, hence one executable running on a PC Linux might not be able to run on an ARM Linux. It does not seem so obvious to use the AVR buildchain (itself used by Arduino) on a Respberry Pi.

Comment: *Well I would say this one* - that wasn't referenced in the question. I am not assuming that is what the OP is on about.

Comment: @TomCarpenter *Tell me, would you consider that bloat?* - not really. You are asking if 246 bytes of code, which allow you to pass a variable rather than a constant is bloat? No, code which does something has to take space.

Comment: If I write some code that takes 16 bytes, and you can rewrite it to take 8 bytes, you can say that my code is 100% bloated. But it's only 8 bytes longer! You need to distinguish between percentages and actual values.

Comment: Like, if country X has one murder per year, and next year it has two murders, you can say that the number of murders doubled! Shock, horror, employ more police! But, it's only one more murder.

Comment: Guys, your comments seem totally unrelated to the original question. The OP did not even mention "bloated".

Comment: @NickGammon but we aren't taking about 1 or 2 bytes, we are talking about 10% of the ATTiny85 flash! And on a relatively slow MCU those extra instructions are bloated in speed as well. At 8MHz direct port manipulation will take 250ns, whereas digitalWrite will take about 30us, which again is a massive overhead. I understand the reason behind the abstraction, but I think the point was it's very costly on very small MCUs.

Comment: Yes, but if you abandon the IDE, you also abandon `digitalWrite`. My point was that you can abandon `digitalWrite` and still use the IDE.